# How To Pick a Database?

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, nosql

In this day and age, with a new NoSQL databases popping up every weekend..

Are there any good and up-to-date resources on how to pick a database(s) that will suit your web application needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in trade-offs and feature comparisons Wikipedia tends to be updated more than others.

Relational Database Comparison: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

NoSQL Feature Comparison: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_structured_storage_software

If you want a more direct answer you can always post the requirements you have and you'll get a lot of helpful answers. It's a pretty broad subject and, other than feature comparison matrices like the ones above, you'll mainly get subjective answers unless you have an objective question (ie specific requirements).

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra vs MongoDB vs CouchDB vs Redis vs Riak vs HBase vs Membase vs Neo4j [comparison](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)

[NoRAM DB](http://www.dotkam.com/2011/07/06/noram-db-if-it-does-not-fit-in-ram-i-will-quietly-die-for-you/) => “If It Does Not Fit in RAM, I Will Quietly Die For You”

Although I would also advise considering a SQL data back end ( e.g. PostgreSQL, [Drizzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drizzle_%28database_server%29) ) with a cache layer, e.g. Redis on top of it. Unless you have an actual reason to use NoSQL. The reason can by the way be *NoSQL is cool* and *I'd like to learn it*, but if that is all, usually it may hurt at the end.

Does the problem have to do with [money transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399533/is-nosql-database-good-for-online-money-transaction-management)? Are you going to have a [distributed system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546775/does-using-nosql-make-sense-for-a-non-distributed-system-trying-to-understand-e/7550482#7550482)?

Comment: Any comparisons with regular SQL DB's?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem to solve? Because that what should guide your decision the most.

Comment: @Radagaisus, here is a good concise comparison of [SQL vs NoSQL Databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database)

Comment: I want to understand the differences between the databases from a developer point of view